# Dimensional analysis: physical meaning of Pi groups

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Given a physical problem, I know how to use Buckingham theorem in order to obtain the required number of indipendent non-dimensional Pi groups. However, I am not sure about how to interpret physically these groups.

I know that, for example, in fluid dynamics the Pi groups do have a physical meaning. But my question here is more general: given a physical problem which provides "k" indipendent Pi groups, can I gain some physical insight from them?

An example: suppose I listed too many variables in my problem (I mean that some of them are not necessary, because they don't really affect sensibly the physical process I am studying). Because of my "bad" listing, with the Buckingham theorem I will calculate more Pi groups than necessary. Now, could I somehow "see" from these Pi groups (and the value they assume in the experiments) that I actually made a bad listing? And even better, could I deduce directly from them which are the unneceseary variables that I added to the problem?

Comment: Of course not! Dimensional analysis is not magic. It is literally just bookwork, matching up $3$ exponents. It can't do the thinking for you.

Comment: In fluid dynamics, if Reynolds number has high values I know that viscosity can be neglected as a variable (since inertia forces dominate over viscous forces). Are you saying that I cannot do similar reasoning with a different physical problem (which has different Pi groups)? Maybe the key is that I must know the model equations in advance in order to do similar statements?